# Simple login PHP script refreshing the page

Tags: php

I have a simple PHP login script that directs the user to dashboard.php if the login is successful. Currently, all it is doing is refreshing the page.

```
    <?php 
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    // startar sesion
    session_start(); 

// username and password
$userName = "user";
$password = "pass";
}

if (isset($_POST["userName"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) { 

    if ($_POST["userName"] == $userName && $_POST["password"] == $password) { 

    header( 'Location: dashboard.php' ) ; 
    } 
        // wrong login - message
        else {echo 'foo';} 
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: you have only started session but doesn't store anything to session...any reason ?

Comment: Check your request/response and see what your post variables are

Comment: try print_r($_POST);die(); after session_start(); if there are really keys userName and password

Comment: Were like hawks :) NullPointer and Jaromír BaGricek Navara

Comment: @NullPointer You're right. I removed session_start() and the same thing happened.

Comment: @ColbyAley your code should works fine ....

Comment: @JaromírBaGricekNavara Ok, I fixed the casing but now I don't even have to press the submit button to be redirected.

Comment: if (isset($_POST["submit"])) { is closed too early

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php 

session_start(); 

 // username and password
 $_SESSION['user'] = "user";
 $_SESSION['pass']= "pass";


if (isset($_POST["userName"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) { 

if ($_POST["userName"] == $_SESSION['user'] && $_POST["password"] ==    $_SESSION['pass']) { 

header( 'Location: dashboard.php' ) ; 
} 
    // wrong login - message
    else {echo 'foo';} 
}
?>
```

That just fixes your original code, however i would lean to more like this...

```
 <?
  session_start(); //always at the top of each page

  If empty($_SESSION){ header('location':'login.php')}

  else {header('location':'dashboard.php');
```

Then you rewrite login to always assign session user and pass if the credentials have been verified authenticated

Check post, if post exists compare to vals, if user password match, write them respective to their session array nodes, the redirect to dashboard which should also have thatfunctionality i outlined above at the top of its page to check session

Also do not store the users password in the session, just the verified user name should suffice and keep your site clean from potential intruders hacking in and stealing passwords of others

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I still have a few random bugs that are a different topic, but that seemed to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
// startar sesion
session_start(); 

// username and password
 $userName = "user";
 $password = "pass";
}

if (isset($_POST["userName"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) { 

if ($_POST["userName"] == $userName && $_POST["password"] == $password) { 

header( 'Location: dashboard.php' ) ; 
die();
}else {
echo 'foo';} 
}
?>
```

Try this It might help

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "1")
    {
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    if ((isset($_POST['username'])) && (isset($_POST['password'])))
            {
            if ($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password)
                    {
                    //header redirect
                    header("Location: http://www.google.com");
                    }
            else
                    {
                    print "Some error";
                    }
            }
    else
            {
            print "Some error, most likely empty fields.";
            }
    }
?>
```

Since I don't see you doing anything with the session_start(); I decided not to use it, you can test it out here http://admin.swooshleads.com/test/test.html